# Node Sending Data to InfluxDB with historical timestamp

Tags: node.js, influxdb, influxdb-2

I am trying to write data to influx with the Node-Influx Library.
I want to write historical data to influx using the timestamp in the data and the timestamp value in influx.

```
export class DeviceInfluxDbAccessor extends BaseInfluxDbAccessor {
    public writeDeviceReading(device: Device) {
        const fields = {
            timestamp: device.timestamp
            voltage1: device.voltage1,
        };

        this.influx
            .writePoints([
                {
                    measurement: "Device",
                    fields,
                },
            ])
            .then(() => console.log(`Wrote ${device.id} status to influx.`))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

However the timestamp data seams to be overitten by the influx timestamp

Comment: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4150

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB assumes that timestamps have nanosecond precision. So, while inserting multiply timestamp by 1000000.

```
const fields = {
      timestamp: device.timestamp*1000000
      voltage1: device.voltage1,
};
```